Appwrite URL ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
I am trying to connect to Appwrite using the URL and ProjectIDmy code
My .env.local file is also setup correctly
On running my application this is the error the console shows:
enter image description here
I have logged the url value and it shows undefined.
url used:
'https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1'
